# "Makadesh Yisrael v'Roshei Chadashim" on Rosh HaShanah

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, mistakes

If someone ends off the bracha on Rosh HaShanah "makadesh yisrael v'roshei chadashim" (the text for Rosh Chodesh) instead of "v'yom hazichoron" (the correct text for Rosh Hashanah) are they [yotzee](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/608) [b'dieved](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702)? The Mateh Ephraim in Siman 582 says that if one ends off "makdesh yisrael v'hazmanim" (the text for other holidays) then they are not yotzee. Is this similar? Is this worse? Perhaps a problem since they didn't mention "v'yom hazichron" at all?

Comment: _Kidush_? _Sh'mone esre_? _Haftara_?

Comment: Is this question only for the first day? As the second day Rosh HaShana is definitely not Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: @GershonGold, it's _rosh chodesh_ to the same extent it's _Rosh Hashana_, no? (And we do include the _korban musaf_ of _r"ch_ in its _musaf_ prayer as we do the first day.)

Comment: @msh210, 582 is talking about Nusah HaTefillah for R"H and 'Asereth Yemei Teshuvah. I assume that's what the question is about.

Comment: For the record, +1 from me. ;-)

Comment: Seth - We get along afterall ;).